# Stability of a line of equilibria

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm working with a nonlinear autonomous system $x'=f(x)$. This system stays in $\mathbb{R}^n_+$ whenever it begins there, and it has a ray of equilibria, i.e. there is a positive vector $x_0$ so that for any $a \geq 0$, $f(ax_0)=0$. The linearization of the system at these equilibria has strictly negative real eigenvalues, except for a single zero eigenvalue. The eigenvector for this zero eigenvalue corresponds to the fact that a perturbation in the direction of $x_0$ leaves the system at another equilibrium.

From this can I conclude that the ray (excluding the origin, if need be) as a whole is asymptotically stable? That is, can I conclude that if I consider an initial condition which is a small perturbation from $bx_0$ for $b \geq 0$, the system will tend to $cx_0$ for some $c \geq 0$, possibly different from $b$? This seems intuitive, but I know that there can be subtle issues when the linearization has eigenvalues with zero real part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curve of equilibria is an example of an invariant manifold, for which the stable and unstable manifold theory applies. In your case, if you do not have eigenvalues with positive or zero real part other then the one, which is responsible for the pertrubations along your ray, hence locally the neighborhood of your ray is the stable manifold, and hence attracting.

The exact statement and a proof can be found in Hirsch, Pugh, Shub: "Invariant manifolds", Springer LNM 538 (1977), Theorem 4.1.

Comment: I am not so sure of what Theorem 4.1 says about an analogue of *asymptotic* stability. There is mention of a collection of points which do not stray far from the invariant manifold but there is no mention of relaxing back down to the invariant manifold. Unfortunately my differential geometry skills are quite limited, is there any further help you can give on this part of the issue?

Comment: @Ian As far as I can see and recall, your description of your problem is that the whole neighborhood of the curve of equilibria belongs to the stable manifold of your invariant curve. By the definition of stable manifold, any solution starting in it will approach your curve with time, and hence your curve is attracting. Whether it is also stable (i.e., solutions do not leave a small neighborhood of your invariant curve) I am now not sure, and my words " hence you can say that the curve of equilibria is asymptotically stable." should be removed.

Comment: @Ian However, since in your case the whole space coincides with the stable manifold, I really believe that it must be also stable, but do not think I have a better reference for this.